# ¿cómo agregar boton "ver más" a un textview para aumentar su tamaño fijo en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hola alguien sabe cómo puedo agregar "ver más" a un textview para tener su tamaño fijo y que una vez el contenido lo supere aparezca este botón para expandirlo, algo así como aparece en Facebook ??

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Revisa [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice de esta forma, averiguo si el texto sobrepasa el tamaño del textview, si es asi entonces muestro un bottom ver mas, la cual el boton lo use para abrirme un modal con el textview con un scroll view.

Es una extension para el textview devuelve la ultima linea visible o -1 si todas las lineas se ven.
Esta funcion tiene que ser llamada cuando el textview tenga layout o retorna -1

```
fun TextView.isContentClippedHeight(): Int {
    val layout = this.layout ?: return -1
    val h = this.height - (this.paddingBottom + this.paddingTop)
    for (line in 0 until layout.lineCount) {
        val bottom = layout.getLineTop(line + 1)
        if ( bottom >= h) {
            return line
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: La pregunta tiene el tag "Java", tu código está es Kotlin, por favor ajústalo al tag de la pregunta.